# Video is not getting paused in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I m using viewpager and its adapter i m displaying image and video as per condition.

I don't have fragment because i m using *PagerAdapter*.

**Code:**

```
 pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);

    pager.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pageChangeListener.onPageSelected(pager.getCurrentItem());
        }
    });
}

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        View view = mediaFullScreenImageAdapter.getActiveView(pager);
        if (selectedPhotosByDate.get(position).getMessagetype().equalsIgnoreCase("VIDEO")) {
            CustomVideoPlayer video_player = (CustomVideoPlayer) view.findViewById(R.id.video_player);
            if (video_player.isPlaying()) {
                Log.v("THISCALLEDD", "Y" + " : " + position);
                video_player.pause();
            }
        }
    }
};


 @Nullable
public View getActiveView(final ViewPager viewPager) {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = viewPager.getAdapter();
    if (null == adapter || adapter.getCount() == 0 || viewPager.getChildCount() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    int position;
    final int currentPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

    for (int i = 0; i < viewPager.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View child = viewPager.getChildAt(i);
        final ViewPager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewPager.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        if (layoutParams.isDecor) {
            continue;
        }
        final Field positionField;
        try {
            positionField = ViewPager.LayoutParams.class.getDeclaredField("position");
            positionField.setAccessible(true);
            position = positionField.getInt(layoutParams);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            break;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            break;
        }
        if (position == currentPosition) {
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Update:**

```
 selectedPhotosByDate = appDatabase.chatMessagesDao().getMediaByGroupId(topicid, "Y");


    if (selectedPhotosByDate.size() > 0 && selectedPhotosByDate != null) {

        mediaFullScreenImageAdapter = new MediaFullScreenImageAdapter(MediaFullScreenSlideActivity.this, selectedPhotosByDate);
        pager.setAdapter(mediaFullScreenImageAdapter);

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedPhotosByDate.size(); i++) {
            if (messageid == selectedPhotosByDate.get(i).getMessageId()) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        pager.setCurrentItem(position);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(selectedPhotosByDate.size());
    }
```

I am able to get logcat value . But my video doesn't get pause.

If my video is playing and user swipe for other item playing video must be paused.

Advanced help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd pause all videos except the `int position` of onPageSelected

Comment: But i have to get video player from adapter which will be get by its position

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onpageselected), `onPageSelected` is called when a new page is selected. That means, the active view that you are trying to get using the `currentItem` from the ViewPager will return you the current selected item rather than the previously selected item. So your reference to `video_player` is also wrong and hence it is not working.

A simple way to do this is to have a variable `currentPosition`. Update it in `onPageSelected` but before updating, get its view and pause the video. This way whenever you access it, you will first get the previous index and then you will update it to the current index for the next time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with adding some code?

Comment: The code required for this is not a simple snippet. Rather it is a code that will span multiple functions. Would suggest you to read the answer, try to implement and clarify wherever you get stuck

Comment: I have done with this.  _@Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            previousPosition = position;
            View view = pager.getChildAt(previousPosition);
            CustomVideoPlayer video_player = (CustomVideoPlayer) view.findViewById(R.id.video_player);
            video_player.pause();

        }_. Still not working.

Comment: `previousPosition = position` should be after `video_player.pause()`. That's what I mentioned in the answer

Comment: _@Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            View view = pager.getChildAt(position);
            CustomVideoPlayer video_player = (CustomVideoPlayer) view.findViewById(R.id.video_player);
            video_player.pause();
            previousPosition = position;
        }_ This doesn't work too.

Comment: Looks like correct. You would need to debug more at your end and see if you are getting the correct reference to video_player.

Comment: But after pause the video _previousPosition_ is not using anywhere.

Comment: Can you debug at your end if you are getting the correct reference of video_player?

Comment: I have checked. I m getting null value with position.

Comment: This is i have updated. _View view = pager.getChildAt(previousPosition);
            CustomVideoPlayer video_player = (CustomVideoPlayer) view.findViewById(R.id.video_player);
            video_player.pause();

            if (position > 0) {
                previousPosition = position - 1;
            } else {
                previousPosition = position;
            }_

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding ,you want to pause previous video when user swipe in viewpager .

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    View view = mediaFullScreenImageAdapter.getActiveView(pager);
    if (selectedPhotosByDate.get(position).getMessagetype().equalsIgnoreCase("VIDEO")) {
        CustomVideoPlayer video_player = (CustomVideoPlayer) view.findViewById(R.id.video_player);
        if (video_player.isPlaying()) {
            Log.v("THISCALLEDD", "Y" + " : " + position);
            video_player.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

you are getting view object of current active position ,but you want to pause video of (position - 1 ),you need to have view object of previous position .

Comment: I have done with this. `@Override public void onPageSelected(int position) { previousPosition = position; View view = pager.getChildAt(previousPosition); CustomVideoPlayer video_player = (CustomVideoPlayer) view.findViewById(R.id.video_player); video_player.pause(); }`. Still not working.

Comment: if(position > 0) previousPosition = position - 1 ;

Comment: _@Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            previousPosition = position-1;
            View view = pager.getChildAt(previousPosition);
            CustomVideoPlayer video_player = (CustomVideoPlayer) view.findViewById(R.id.video_player);
            video_player.pause();

        }_ this doesn't work.

Comment: Ashish . Can you please help me ? I need help

Comment: @PiyushGupta ..can you share all the related fragment / activity / adapter .

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved the issue.

I moved this code

```
   View view = mediaFullScreenImageAdapter.getActiveView(pager);
   CustomVideoPlayer video_player = (CustomVideoPlayer) view.findViewById(R.id.video_player);
   video_player.pause();
```

to `onPageScrolled()` method instead of `onPageSelected()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with a Youtube video playing as an embedded iFrame in a WebView:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        // NOTE: this workaround pauses any playing Youtube video in the WebView, if the video screen is being switched out.
        // This works by getting the ViewPager#focusedChild, which will be the WebView if that screen is currently in focus,
        // before the next selected ViewPager screen gets switched-to/loaded.
        viewPager.focusedChild?.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.video_view)?.onPause()
        // NOTE: we do a postDelay below, to ensure the WebView gets put back into its resume state, if it being switched to.
        // This is delayed, so that this happens after the ViewPager screen with the WebView, has time to load it into place.
        postDelayed({ viewPager.focusedChild?.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.video_view)?.onResume() }, 200)
    }
})
```